# Possibility of binding multiple PyGame windows

Tags: python, user-interface, pygame

Is there any way to bind two windows from seprate processes together using Python/Pygame? By binding I mean in two possible ways:

1. A large window that contains two smaller windows
2. Two separate windows which appear side to side (perhaps using OS environment variables?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try running two separate programs. I just ran two of my pygame programs separately, they work fine. Run one using the other, maybe? Or, if that doesn't work, put use two surfaces as screens, and draw one into the other.

Comment: I used subprocess.Popen() method and used Inter Process Communication to exchange data.

Answer (score 1):

Interprocess communication is probably the simplest.  The issue though is that SDL is fundamentally not set up for multiple windows.

Probably the best long-term solution is to set up with wxPython, and then use PyGame inside of it.  This will let you have all manner of windows with PyGame renderers.